# How to walk the methods and their properties contained in a DLL?

Tags: javascript, dll, vbscript

Using preferably JScript, but VBscript will also do, how does one walk a DLL obtaining the properties and their attributes contained therein?
Why? Because it would be good to ascertain the attributes of certain objects such as their datatypes at runtime rather than having to hard-code them before hand. An example of their use would be to initialise fields to their default values, e.g., spaces for strings, zeros for binaries and current date for dates.

Cheers, John

Comment: And what kind of DLL are we talking about? A normal win32 dll which exports some functions? Or a COM/ActiveX library? Or a .Net Assembly? I assume the last since you are talking about attributes.

Answer (score 1):

[VBSEdit](http://www.vbsedit.com) will at least show you methods and properties of DLLs for VBScript when you create an object of that type in a script.